# Access Session attribute on jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to access a session attribute from a jsp page which is set and dispatched by a servlet, but I am getting the error message "jsp:attribute must be the subelement of a standard or custom action". What could be wrong, am I accessing it incorrectly? The following is the code snippet.

---

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
    session.setAttribute("Questions", getQuestion());
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("Questions"));
    RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("DisplayQuestions.jsp");
    req.forward(request, response);
}

private QuestionBookDAO getQuestion(){
    QuestionBookDAO q = new QuestionBookDAO();
    q.setQuestion("First Question");
    q.setQuestionPaperID(100210);
    q.setSubTopic("Java");
    q.setTopic("Threads");
    return q;
}
```

I am able to set the session attribute successfully. But when I try to access the same in my jsp file (below), I am getting a runtime error

```
    <jsp:useBean id="Questions" type="com.cet.evaluation.QuestionBook" scope="session">
    <jsp:getProperty property="Questions" name="questionPaperID"/>
    <jsp:getProperty property="Questions" name="question"/>
    </jsp:useBean>
```

The bean QuestionBook contains two private variables **questionPaperID** and **question**
I run the application on Tomcat and below is the error thrown.

```
type Exception report

message 

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /DisplayQuestions.jsp(15,11) jsp:attribute must be the subelement of a standard or custom action
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1160)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1461)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1670)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1020)
            ....
```

Answer (score 36):

You should definitely avoid using `<jsp:...>` tags. They're relics from the past and should always be avoided now.

Use the JSTL.

Now, wether you use the JSTL or any other tag library, accessing to a bean **property** needs your bean to have this property. A property is not a private instance variable. It's an information accessible via a public getter (and setter, if the property is writable). To access the questionPaperID property, you thus need to have a

```
public SomeType getQuestionPaperID() {
    //...
}
```

method in your bean.

Once you have that, you can display the value of this property using this code :

```
<c:out value="${Questions.questionPaperID}" />
```

or, to specifically target the session scoped attributes (in case of conflicts between scopes) :

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.Questions.questionPaperID}" />
```

Finally, I encourage you to name scope attributes as Java variables : starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Agreed.  The uppercase definitely threw me for a second.

Comment: Do you need to set the session as an attribute in the servlet?

Comment: @gmustudent: session attributes should be used for information belonging to the whole session. If they're relevant for the current request only, then request attributes should be used.

Comment: So I can grab a users session. Get data from an object in the session. Update that session object within the servlet. And then go back to the view and use that data. by making a call like you did above?

Answer (score 15):

You don't need the `jsp:useBean` to set the model if you already have a controller which prepared the model.

Just access it plain by EL:

```
<p>${Questions.questionPaperID}</p>
<p>${Questions.question}</p>
```

or by JSTL `<c:out>` tag if you'd like to HTML-escape the values or when you're still working on legacy Servlet 2.3 containers or older when EL wasn't supported in template text yet:

```
<p><c:out value="${Questions.questionPaperID}" /></p>
<p><c:out value="${Questions.question}" /></p>
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

---

Unrelated to the problem, the normal practice is by the way to start attribute name with a lowercase, like you do with normal variable names.

```
session.setAttribute("questions", questions);
```

and alter EL accordingly to use `${questions}`.

Also note that you don't have any [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) tag in your code. It's all plain JSP.

Comment: That should be EL in JSP, is there any other way to achieve it if i restrict EL on my pages?

Comment: I don't understand this comment. Please revise your terminology. The given answer should work fine and is the right way. In the ancient ages you could use *scriptlets* in JSP as well, but this is discouraged since a decade.

Comment: @Vijay : why would you avoid using EL? Do you like when things are harder than necessary? BalusC is right : EL is there for good reasons. Use it.

Comment: Thanks, i do agree with you and i am not against using EL, but if i have <el-ignored>true</el-ignored> on my DD or my boss doesn't agree to use it then how can i achieve it? I was searching to find if JSTL and custom tags could help.

Comment: Ah yes, this way. If EL is ignored by DD, then you already cannot use JSTL. Your best resort is `<jsp:xxx>` tags like you already have or just old fashioned *scriptlets* (or look for another job/project). The exception which you got is by the way in no way correlatable to the code snippet. You've got a `<jsp:attribute>` somewhere in a wrong place. Ensure that you're running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Kudos for the answer, and for posting the SO Wiki page on servlets.  Not being able to use EL can be quite a hindrance to writing effective, clean code.