# How can i get a session variable (setted with a servlet) in jstl

Tags: java, servlets, jstl

i'm making an application with jsp and java servlets, the problem is 
i need to check if certain session variable is set (i set it on the servlet)
on my jsp file. I'm using jstl for cheking this, my code is:
 `String siguiente = "/vista2.jsp";
...
if(request.getParameter("User").equals(usdb) && request.getParameter("pass").equals(passDB)){
                    out.println("Coinciden usuario y contraseña
");
                    HttpSession hs = request.getSession(true);
                    Integer par = (Integer)hs.getAttribute("varS");
                    if(par==null){
                        Random rg = new Random();
                        par = new Integer(rg.nextInt(1000));
                        hs.setAttribute("varS", par);
                    }
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(siguiente);
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                    break;
                }`

and in my jsp code i'm trying

`<c:choose>

            <c:when test="${varS!=null}">

             <c:redirect url="/index.jsp" />

           </c:when>

           <c:otherwise>

             <h1>Has entrado exitosamente</h1>   

          </c:otherwise>

      </c:choose>`

And even though i access the page directly(without accessing the servlet before) the page doesn't redirect

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Session attribute on jstl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889431/access-session-attribute-on-jstl)

Comment: If you want to test `null` checks, use `${not empty varS}`. Also, make sure you don't have a request attribute with the same name.

Comment: no @tieTYT, i've read that post but it didn't help me, and i don't even catch his servlet code so it doesn't work for me

Comment: it's solved! thanks @LuiggiMendoza, i modified it to <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.hs.varS}"

Comment: You're welcome. Still are you sure you need to use `hs` in the middle of your EL?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well, it doesn't work other way so i guess it is necessary

Comment: Then your problem is that you have a session attribute `hs` which inside contains a `varS` variable. This is very strange to recognize from your given code.