# jsp sql query print from table, equal symbol expected error

Tags: sql, jsp, session-variables, taglib, javadb

I want to print values from a table where the username equals to the current user, im getting the current user from session.getattribute("username"), but the sql statement gives an error saying "equal symbol expected", can you tell me whats wrong with the below code and how to do it properly, thank you

```
<sql:query var="studentcourse"
           dataSource="${vle}"
           SELECT course_name FROM studentcourse WHERE username = '<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>'
                    </sql:query>
 <p>user = <%=session.getAttribute("username")%>
 <% System.out.println("username");%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it in JSTL variable, instead of trying directly. You should use `JSTL` taglib,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Try this code,

```
<c:set var="userName" value= "${sessionScope.username}"/>
<sql:query var="studentcourse"
       dataSource="${vle}">
     SELECT course_name FROM studentcourse WHERE username = ? ;
    <sql:param value="${userName}"/>
</sql:query>
```

You can access the session scoped variables inside JSP page in two different ways,

```
<c:out value='${sessionScope["username"]}' /><br/>
<c:out value='${sessionScope.username}'/>
```

References,

- [Access Session attribute on jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889431/access-session-attribute-on-jstl)
- [SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html)

  Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find the above answer fixed your issue, mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), might be useful for others.